# Install chmsee in the ArchLinux,throw Error: Platform version '8.0' is not compatible

Tags: xulrunner, arch-linux

when I use the command:

```
sudo yaourt -S chmsee
```

install the chmsee in the Archlinux.

then type the chmsee at the terminator:

```
Error: Platform version '8.0' is not compatible with minVersion >= 2.0b9 
maxVersion <= 7.0.* failed to create drawable
```

I thought cause the xulrunner version is too high,and my system is lower?

if so, how reslove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem in ArchLinux here. My error was:

```
$ chmsee &
Error: Platform version '9.0' is not compatible with
minVersion >= 6.0
maxVersion <= 8.0.*
```

So I solved it modifying in file `/usr/share/chmsee/application.ini` line:

```
MaxVersion=8.0.*
```

with this other one:

```
MaxVersion=9.0.*
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Had the same issue in LMDE today, fixed it. Thanks +1